# Label 3D PCA with gene names

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, 3d, pca

I am implementing a 3D PCA plot using this as a guide https://python-graph-gallery.com/372-3d-pca-result/ . The result gives me an idea how different gene sequences cluster together, in this example I've used 5 different genes, but this must be flexible.

Everything works fine except the legend doesn't line up with the colors in the plot. It just prints whatever I give it. So my question is - what to write instead of 'label=my_color'? c=my_color and cmap="gist_rainbow" work, so how to get label to work in a similar fashion? I need gene names or at least numbers. I thought that making a Series with a map of row to gene name would work but it just gets printed as my_color does here.

Is this possible in one line? I'd really rather not split it up as per this example http://creativemorphometrics.co.vu/blog/2014/07/07/python-project-and-explore/

## I first make a tmp df by extracting the genes I want:

```
mask = (all_df['Emm'] == 'EMM82') | (all_df['Emm'] == 'EMM1') | (all_df['Emm'] == 'EMM65') | (all_df['Emm'] == 'EMM12') | (all_df['Emm'] == 'EMM75')
tmp = all_df[mask]
```

## Convert to a matrix:

```
xdata = tmp.as_matrix(df.columns)
```

## Make a color code for the genes:

```
emm_nos = [emm for emm in all_df['Emm'] if emm in ['EMM82','EMM1','EMM65','EMM12', 'EMM75']]
encoder_emm = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit(emm_nos)
my_color=pd.Series(encoder_emm.transform(emm_nos))
```

## Then follow the tutorial:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("white")

pca = PCA(n_components=3)
pca.fit(xdata)
xdata = pca.transform(xdata)

result=pd.DataFrame(pca.transform(xdata), columns=['PCA%i' % i for i in 
range(3)], index=target_names)

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(25, 19))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(result['PCA0'], result['PCA1'], result['PCA2'], c=my_color, 
cmap="gist_rainbow", s=60, label=my_color)

xAxisLine = ((min(result['PCA0']), max(result['PCA0'])), (0, 0), (0,0))
ax.plot(xAxisLine[0], xAxisLine[1], xAxisLine[2], 'r')
yAxisLine = ((0, 0), (min(result['PCA1']), max(result['PCA1'])), (0,0))
ax.plot(yAxisLine[0], yAxisLine[1], yAxisLine[2], 'r')
zAxisLine = ((0, 0), (0,0), (min(result['PCA2']), max(result['PCA2'])))
ax.plot(zAxisLine[0], zAxisLine[1], zAxisLine[2], 'r')

ax.set_xlabel("PC1")
ax.set_ylabel("PC2")
ax.set_zlabel("PC3")
ax.set_title("PCA on EMM SNP dist")
plt.legend(loc='upper left', numpoints=1, ncol=3, fontsize=8, 
bbox_to_anchor=(0, 0))
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

I'm not allowed to post images so I've linked the resulting image here https://github.com/shimbalama/common_modules/blob/master/5emms.png?raw=true

How to get a lengend with genes names?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This surely is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You increase your chance to get a good answer by creating one.

Comment: Okay I'll work on it, sorry - new at this (as it seems most questions have already been asked...). Can I be as brief as 'How to get legend to match colors in ax.scatter(result['PCA0'], result['PCA1'], result['PCA2'], c=my_color, cmap="gist_rainbow", s=60, label=my_color)'?

Comment: If this reproduces your problem, when I paste the code in my IDE - sure.